# Do we need to escape anything in "Fn::Base64: !Sub" in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

When we use [Fn::Base64: !Sub |](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) for the UserData section in a YAML CloudFormation template, do we need to escape things like double quotes, backslashes and the like?

Example syntax:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets wordpress_install --region ${AWS::Region}
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made an experimental UserData section:

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub |
  <script>
  cd "C:\\Windows"
  cd \"C:\\Windows\"
  </script>
```

And then looked at the userdata passed to the EC2 instance in `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` from inside the machine:

```
<script>
cd "C:\\Windows"
cd \"C:\\Windows\"
</script>
```

So the user-data was indeed passed as is and nothing needed to be escaped.